# matlab input-output: convert square inches to square cm?

Tags: matlab

Matlab input output: how do I write a code to convert area from square inches to square centimeters and then print the results in both square inches and square centimeters? I know convert 1 square inch = 2.54^2 square cm, and I know how to assign variables, etc. I'm just really frustrated with MatLab.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: So you're looking for a fine matlab introduction? Here ya go: http://www.mathworks.com/moler/intro.pdf

Answer (score 0):

To get you started, and as reference for your problem, here is a solution to your question:

Put this in a file called `sqinch2sqcm.m`

```
function sqcm = sqinch2sqcm(sqinc)
    sqcm = (2.54)^2 * sqinc;
end
```

If this file is on your matlab path (just in the current directory of matlab ([look here if you don't know what that is](http://etools.fernuni.ch/matlab/matlab2/en/image/gui_currentdir_s.png)) is enough), you can try to execute `sqinch2sqcm(4)` to test your function.